# read from excel file in CPLEX Studio, cell contain a list

Tags: optimization, cplex, ilog

I am getting the data from the "data.xlsx" file using this code:

this part from the .mod file
`int n=...; range items = 1..n; int values[items] = ...;`

and this part from .dat file:
`n from SheetRead(excelsheet, "Sheet1!A3"); values from SheetRead(excelsheet, "Sheet1!A7");` 
the list of values is in the cell A7, i want to load it into the var values,
by this manner i faced an error which says:
**Exception from IBM ILOG Concert excel size of the range is not the  **

load a list from excel file in cplex

Answer (score 0):

2 steps :

First you read the cell as a string.

In [excel OPL](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/excel-rocket-science-optimization-alex-fleischer/), see

```
SheetConnection s("read1cell.xlsx");

value from SheetRead(s,"B1");

value2 to SheetWrite(s,"B5");
```

and then with [OPL scripting](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/javascript-within-opl-cplex-alex-fleischer/) you can [turn the string into an array of values](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/oplscripting/blob/main/splitstringintoarray.mod)

```
string s="1;2;8;1000";

int arsize;

execute
{
  ar=s.split(";");
  writeln("size =",ar.length);
  arsize=ar.length;
}

range r=1..arsize;
int resultarray[r];

execute
{
  ar=s.split(";");
  for(var i in r) resultarray[i]=Opl.atoi(ar[i-1]);
  writeln("resultarray = ",resultarray);
}

/*

which gives

size =4
resultarray =  [1 2 8 1000]

*/
```